# Quick question on $x^{3}-2$ and field extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

For the case where $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=[E:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2):\mathbb{Q}] = (2)(3) = 6$

E is the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2,i\sqrt{3})$

I understand why $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2):\mathbb{Q}]$ has degree 3 but I don't understand why $[E:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)]$ has degree 2. I know this leaves the element $(\sqrt[3]2)$ fixed and only permutates E.

Comment: We can't explain that since you haven't told us what E is...

Comment: "and only permutates E".....Is there a question about the Galois group hidden in here too?  We're here to help you get unstuck, but we need a clearly stated question first.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified : E is the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2,i\sqrt{3})$

Comment: What "only permutes $E$"?  To answer the part of your question that ends with a question mark, $E$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ extended with a root of the quadratic $x^2 - 3$, and hence has degree  at most $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.  As $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ doesn't contain a root of this quadratic, the degree is exactly $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{E}:=\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2},i\sqrt{3})$ it is the smallest extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that contains $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $i\sqrt{3}$ the polynomials that generate those elements are $x^3-2$ and $x^2+3$ which means that $[\mathbb{E}:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})]=2$ because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ already contains $x^3-2$ and the extension only needs to add $x^2+3$ which has degree 2.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $x^2+3$ is irreducable over $\mathbb Q(2^{1/3})$. Hence $|E:\mathbb Q(2^{1/3})|=2$.

Comment: @SquiresMcGee: You are wecome.